# How to Sort table Header in angular

Tags: angular

In my angular project, I get some data from API and display it in the table I need to sort the data when the table header is clicked. any library or ready pipe do it,
if not how can I do it from scratch?

**My template**

```
        <div class="mainTbl">
            <div>
                <div class="group ">
                    <input type="text" required [(ngModel)]="term" >
                    <span class="highlight"></span>
                    <span class="bar"></span>
                    <span class="btn btn-secondary serhIco"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></span>
                    <label>بحث</label>

                </div>
                <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered table-fixed-header" >
                    <thead>

                        <tr>
                            <th>#</th>
                            <th>الاسم</th>
                            <th>الهاتف</th>
                            <th>العنوان</th> 
                            <th>الحساب</th>
                            <th>ملاحظات</th>
                            <th>إجراءات
                                <button class="btn btn-success">
                                    <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
                                </button>
                            </th>

                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>

                        <tr *ngFor="let item of clients | filter:term | paginate: { itemsPerPage: 2, currentPage: p }">

                            <td>{{item.id}} </td>
                            <td>{{item.name}} </td>
                            <td>{{item.phone}} </td>
                            <td>{{item.address}} </td>
                            <td>{{item.account}} </td>
                            <td>{{item.nots}} </td>
                            <td class="text-center">
                                <button class='btn btn-info'>
                                    <span class="fa fa-edit"></span>
                                </button>
                                <button class="btn btn-danger">
                                    <span class="fa fa-trash"></span>
                                </button>
                            </td>


                        </tr>

                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <pagination-controls (pageChange)="p = $event"></pagination-controls>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div> <!-- end main stores tbl-->
</div>
<!-- start main stores tbl-->
```

I appreciate anyone helps me.

Comment: Give this a look... https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview#sorting

Comment: thanks for your support I'll check that

Comment: if there any other way, not **Angular Material**,  something simple